# infinite tower of automorphism group

Tags: group-theory

I am learning now on automorphsim groups and I am looking for an example for the following situation:

Let $G$ be a group and denote $M = Aut(G)$. Let $f_1,f_2 \in M$ two different elements. Denote now
$M^{(1)} = Aut(M)$. Assume that there are two different automorphisms $f_1^{(1)}, f_2^{(1)} \in M^{(1)}$
such that for $i=1,2:\,$ $f_i^{(1)}(f_1)=f_2$.

Let now $M^{(2)} = Aut(M^{(1)})$. Assume that there are two different  automorphisms $f_1^{(2)}, f_2^{(2)} \in M^{(2)}$
such that for $i=1,2:\,$ $f_i^{(2)}(f_1^{(1)})=f_2^{(1)}$.

Let now $M^{(3)} = Aut(M^{(2)})$ and so on...

so I have a couple of questions: obviously this construction depends on the choice of the $f_i^{(j)}$'s - however, can one find an example for which: (1) this construction terminates (i.e. for some $j>1$, $M^{(j)}=id$) - I guess
the cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}/n$ would do, (2) this construction never terminates (i.e. for any $j$, $M^{(j)} \neq id$ and one can always find appropriate $f_i^{(j)}$'s).

I actually know that for any finite group $G$, there is a $j$ s.t. $M^{(j)} =  M^{(j+1)}$ (can someone give a hint how to prove it?),  so I assume that answers question (1). But what about infinite groups?

thank you very much

Comment: What makes you think that the automorphism tower of a finite group eventually stabilizes? This is a long-standing open problem. See, for example http://mathoverflow.net/questions/27861

Comment: well, it was only a guess, and after looking at the various questions that were asked in mathoverflow, I see that this is wrong. However, I did  see in mathoverflow that every automorphism tower does stabilize, transfinitely: [here for example](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/5635/does-mathrmaut-mathrmaut-mathrmautg-stabilize)